# WinSCP: Text search on remote files

Tags: search, full-text-search, remote-server, winscp

I use WinSCP to get access on the remote files of our project. How can I search for some text/words in all remote files/directories using WinSCP?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

WinSCP does not support text searching in its primary GUI.

---

But there's a built-in [extension to Search recursively for text in remote directory](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_recursive_search_text).

This is a universal solution that works with SFTP, even if the server does not allow shell access, or even for FTP or WebDAV sessions.

[image]

---

Alternatively, you may be able to make use of WinSCP [console window](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_console) (*Commands > Open Terminal*) to launch the search from the command-line.

```
grep -r "text_to_search_for" *
```

This of course requires a shell access to the server.